# selected value from the drop down list only shows after I clicked the dropdown

Tags: material-design, angular8

I want to the dropdown show the value when editing the user, but it happens only when I clicked the dropdown. When clicking the dropdown then I can see the value selected. What did I do wrong?

**ts**

```
ngOnInit(){ 
    this.checkedClientele = this.clienteles;
    if(this.clienteles)
    { 
        const clienteleArray =this.clienteles.filter(o=>o.ClienteleId==this.user.clienteleId);
        this.checkedClientele = clienteleArray[0];
    }

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
<mat-form-field
    class="mat-form-field-fluid" >
    <mat-select
        placeholder="Clientele"
        formControlName="clientele"
        [(ngModel)]="checkedClientele" >
        <mat-option
            *ngFor="
                let clientele of clienteles"
            [value]="clientele" >
            {{ clientele.Name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
</div>
```